# How to parse data on the backend

Tags: laravel

I am using Angular2 for my frontend and laravel for my back end and I'm having trouble saving the data to the database

Each of the keys in the `Order[]` (ex `prodName`, `prodDesc`) are the same as the column names in the database so I was trying to loop the request and save the data but its not working

```
public function Order(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $order = new Order;

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $input) && !empty($value)) {
         $order->$key = $value;
     }
   }
}
if($order->save()) {
    return response()->json(['order' => $order], 201);
}
```

order.interface.ts

```
export interface Order {
  prodName: string;
  prodDesc: string;
}
```

Adding the item to the order

addToOrder.component.ts

```
orders = [] as Order[];

saveItem(): void {
  this.orders.push({prodName: this.prodName, prodDesc: this.prodDesc});
  this.dataService.save(this.orders).then(() => {
    this.navCtrl.pop(Search);
  });
}
```

How each item is stored in storage

order.storage.ts

```
save(data : Order[]): Promise<any> {
  return this.getData().then((products: any[]) => {
  if (products) {
   products = products.concat(data);
   return this.storage.set('products', products);
  }
  return this.storage.set('products', data);
  });
}
```

How I retrieve the order from storage

order.component.ts

```
private order = [] as Order[];

constructor(public dataService: OrderStorage, public OrderService: OrderService) {

  this.dataService.getData().then((products) => {
    if (products) { 
    this.order = products;
    }
  });
}

onSubmit() {
  this.OrderService.submit(this.order)
    .subscribe();
}
```

Posting the data to the back end

order.service.ts

```
submit(order: Order[]): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(localapi.app, order)
    .map(
      (response: Response) => {});
}
```

Structure of the `order` data being sent

[image]

Retrieving the data on the backend

```
public function Order(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    var_dump($input);
}
```

the var_dump output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's actually `foreach ($input as $key => $arr)`, then you can use your loop:

```
foreach ($input as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
       if (array_key_exists($key, $arr) && !empty($value)) {
            $order->$key = $value;
       }
    }
}
```

The first set of elements you will encounter in your loop are arrays, then you can loop the property off of your array.

Comment: Its still not working. Its saying `prodName` doesn't have a default value

Comment: Okay I figured it out had to change `$input` to `$arr` in the third line like this `(array_key_exists($key, $arr))` but now it is just saving one record

Comment: @ghan Aye, copy paste issues!

Comment: The problem now is that its only saving one record. 5 are being received but only 1 is saved

Comment: I've updated the first post with how I'm saving it maybe thats where the problem is